# Magento 2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5

when I go to the checkout page (only this page) there is an error in 2 scripts that totally disturb the store, I tried to execute all the commands, but it does not adjust this error

already executed all the commands below, but without success

```
rm -rf pub/static/;
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/;
chmod -R 777 var pub;
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f pt_BR;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US;
php bin/magento cache:clean; 
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer; 
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

the two files that are in error are

```
pub/static/version1592851434/frontend/Magento/luma/pt_BR/tippy.js 
pub/static/version1592851434/frontend/Magento/luma/pt_BR/stickyfill.js 



Magento version 2.3.5
```

can anyone help?

Comment: To me those paths look wrong, those js files wont be in a i18 like directory "pt_BR" but rather in either a module Magento_Theme/web.. or the main web/js, try to find the files calling those js's and check their paths

Comment: omg, can u help me to find this files?

Comment: in the shell where you run the commands you mentioned in the question, run: grep -rn tippy.js app/code or grep -rn tippy.js app/design to see what files are calling it

Comment: i get his. main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Magento/luma/pt_BR/stickyfill.js'